# Wordpress wp-admin login facing with HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error) issue

Tags: php, wordpress

My WordPress Wp-admin login www.xxx.com/wp-admin/ is used to fine and working.

But when I log in this time. I am facing with this issue.

> HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was
>   encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

however, I can access this page www.xxx.com/wp-login.php but cant login.

Any body has any idea with this issues . I do really appreciate for all suggestion .

I have tried with php.ini file in /wp-admin/ folder by adding with this code "memory_limit = 128M " , but no luck.

Comment: Did you check the server error log?

Comment: yes , however admin.php is there.                                      [21-Jun-2013 10:38:09] PHP Warning:  require_once(/home2/xxx/public_html/xxx/wp-admin/includes/admin.php) [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home2/xxx/public_html/xxx/wp-admin/admin-

Comment: I had got an internal server error when i updated a plugin.. Check the plugins that you may have updated. It can be one of the issues. Also the error log might give u a good insight..

Answer (score 4):

After having this problem recently, I tried all the solutions mentioned all over the internet and I got nothing.

You might want to try deactivating your plugins as mentioned [Here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/500-internal-server-error-wp-admin-only) amongst many other solutions.

Try renaming your theme directory to deactivate it (can be done via FTP)

Try increasing your PHP MEMORY LIMIT

Try fixing your .htaccess file

All these solutions (detailed [here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-internal-server-error-in-wordpress/)) did not work for me.

I checked the server error log and I found that the problem was simply that the directory "*wp-admin*" was writable by group! 
So simply changing the permission of that directory from **777** to **755** solved the problem for me!

Hope this helps someone

Comment: how you change 777 to 755 or where?

Comment: This too was my issue. For some reason my wp-admin directory was set to 777. You can "reset" the file permissions via FileZilla, or through the file manager in your cpanel. I used FileZilla. Connect to your server, right click the wp-admin directory, click  'File Attributes' and set to 755 (everything read/execute, only owner permissions check off write) but make sure you check off 'Recurse into subdirectories'. Hit Ok and wait for changes.

Comment: thank you so much, you just saved my life sir, Big respect. thank u so much!

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the latest version of PHP (e.g., 5.6 to 7.0) fixed my wp-login.php error.